# Android: handling clicks on image view inside recycler's view item using touch framework

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, touch-event, ontouch

I am trying to capture the clicks on `ImageView` which is enclosed inside the `RecyclerView` item. I have implemented `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` and has gesture detector process the motion events for normal clicks and long press on `RecyclerView` item.

Since I want to have the same touch framework to process touch event on child views inside the `RecylcerView` item, I have set `View.OnTouchListener` with the image view as well, overriding the `onTouch` implementation returning true hoping that the touch shall be consumed by the `ImageView` when it gets clicked.

I am intentionally returning false in `onInterceptTouchEvent` always from the `RecyclerView`, hoping the child views process the event first and if none of them consumes then `RecyclerView`'s item view shall handle the gesture event for clicks during `onTouchEvent` handling.

With the above understanding I am able to receive touch events on the `ImageView` when clicked on it.

The problem is that, when I click on the `RecyclerView` item outside `ImageView`, `RecyclerView`'s `onTouchEvent` is not getting called at all. my understanding of the touch framework is that if child views doesn't process the touch event, the `RecyclerView`'s `onTouchEvent` should get a chance to process the same. However this is not what i am able to achieve.

Can anyone suggest what is happening behind and what is the correct way to process click events for the above?

Comment: Am I getting it right when I say, that you can't override item clicks inside of RecyclerView row? I mean, when you click on ImageView in your row, it will call an action, but the rest part of row becomes untouchable and vice versa?

Answer (score 4):

This will solve your problem:

```
public class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    private int position;
    private OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback;

    public OnItemClickListener(int position, OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback) {
        this.position = position;
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(view, position);
    }

    public interface OnItemClickCallback {
        void onItemClicked(View view, int position);
    }
}
```

Get an instance of 'OnItemClickCallback' interface and put it in your activity or fragment:

```
private OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback = new OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
        // switch(view.getId()) ...
    }
};
```

Then, pass that callback to your recyclerView:

```
recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3"), onItemClickCallback));
```

Finally, this would be your adapter:

```
public class SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<String> mValues;
    private OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback;

    public SimpleStringRecyclerViewAdapter(List<String> items, OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback) {
        mValues = items;
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mTextView;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.mTextView.setText(mValues.get(position));
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position, onItemClickCallback));
        holder.mTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(position, onItemClickCallback));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: very efficient and generic solution.

Comment: Exactly what I needed here