# how can handle with recyclerview item with three options to choose

Tags: android

How can handle with this situation -> I have a list of itens in a recyclerView and I want to choose one of those option: green, yellow or red face to get the value of object from list item I chose 
So I thought something like bellow, but when I select one of those faces anything happens. I think that button click listener doesn't work. Please someone can drive me to a better suggestion that works, give me an example or could me tell what am I doing wrong?

**My adapter**

```
    public class LikeListAdapter extends  RecyclerView.Adapter<LikeListAdapter.LikeItemViewHolder> {

    private List<Goals> goalsList;
private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

    public LikeListAdapter(List<Goals> goalsList) {
        this.goalsList = goalsList;
    }

    @Override
    public LikeItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_like, parent, false);
        return new LikeItemViewHolder(view);
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LikeItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Goals goals = goalsList.get(position);
        if (goals != null && getItemCount() > 0) {
            holder.goalsDescriptionTextView.setText(goals.getDescription());
            holder.happyButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("fretgr", "get Green Point = " + goals.getGreenPoint());
                    setToggleSelection(1);
                }
            });

            holder.sosoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("rtret", "get Yellow Point = " + goals.getYellowPoint());
                    setToggleSelection(2);
                }
            });

            holder.angryButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.e("ewwr", "get Red Point = " + goals.getRedPoint());
                    setToggleSelection(3);
                }
            });

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return goalsList.size();
    }


    public class LikeItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Bind(R.id.description_goalsTextView)
        TextView goalsDescriptionTextView;
        @Bind(R.id.happy)
        ImageView happyButton;
        @Bind(R.id.soso)
        ImageView sosoButton;
        @Bind(R.id.angry)
        ImageView angryButton;

        public LikeItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);

        }
    }

        //  method to access in activity after updating selection
    public List<Goals> getGoalsList() {
        return goalsList;
    }

    public void setToggleSelection(int pointType){
        selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
        if (selectedItems.get(pointType, false)) {
            selectedItems.delete(pointType);
        } else {
            selectedItems.put(pointType, true);
        }
        notifyItemChanged(pointType);
    }

    public int getToggleSelection(){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**My Fragment**

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
        assocGoalsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        assocGoalsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        likeListAdapter = new LikeListAdapter(associateList);
        assocGoalsRecyclerView.setAdapter(likeListAdapter);
        assocGoalsRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(RecycleTouchListener);

private RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener RecycleTouchListener = new RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
            View child = assocGoalsRecyclerView.findChildViewUnder(e.getX(), e.getY());
            if(child!=null && mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)){
                final int position = assocGoalsRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(child);

                final Goals goals = associateList.get(position);
                final Categories c = categoriesList.get(position);
                final int type = likeListAdapter.getToggleSelection();



                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) { }

        @Override
        public void onRequestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(boolean disallowIntercept) { }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer based in another responses and sugestions!!! [Android: handling clicks on image view inside recycler's view item using touch framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449540/android-handling-clicks-on-image-view-inside-recyclers-view-item-using-touch-f?answertab=active#tab-top)

**In My Fragment**

Snippet from fragment:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        layoutManager.scrollToPosition(0);
        assocGoalsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
//        assocGoalsRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(new SimpleDividerItemDecoration(getActivity()));
        assocGoalsRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    likeListAdapter = new LikeListAdapter(associateList, onItemClickCallback);
    assocGoalsRecyclerView.setAdapter(likeListAdapter);

public static class OnItemClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
        private int position;
        private OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback;

        public OnItemClickListener(int position, OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback) {
            this.position = position;
            this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClickCallback.onItemClicked(view, position);
        }

        public interface OnItemClickCallback {
            void onItemClicked(View view, int position);
        }
    }


    private OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback = new OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClicked(View view, int position) {
             switch(view.getId()){
                 case R.id.happy:
                     Log.e("rtetre", "happy assessed and position is = " + position);
                     break;
                 case R.id.soso:
                     Log.e("rwere", "soso assessed and position is = " + position);
                     break;
                 case R.id.angry:
                     Log.e("dfrefgt", "angry assessed and position is = " + position);
                     break;
             }
        }
    };
```

**In My adapter**

```
public class LikeListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LikeListAdapter.LikeItemViewHolder> {

    private List<Goals> goalsList;
    private LikeFragment.OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback;

public LikeListAdapter(List<Goals> goalsList, LikeFragment.OnItemClickListener.OnItemClickCallback onItemClickCallback) {
    this.goalsList = goalsList;
    this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback;
}

@Override
public LikeItemViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_like, parent, false);

    LikeItemViewHolder likeItemViewHolder = new LikeItemViewHolder(view);
    return likeItemViewHolder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(LikeItemViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final Goals goals = goalsList.get(position);
    if (goals != null && getItemCount() > 0) {
        holder.goalsDescriptionTextView.setText(goals.getDescription());
        holder.happyButton.setOnClickListener(new LikeFragment.OnItemClickListener(position, onItemClickCallback));
        holder.sosoButton.setOnClickListener(new LikeFragment.OnItemClickListener(position, onItemClickCallback));
        holder.angryButton.setOnClickListener(new LikeFragment.OnItemClickListener(position, onItemClickCallback));

    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return goalsList.size();
}


public static class LikeItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.description_goalsTextView)
    TextView goalsDescriptionTextView;
    @Bind(R.id.happy)
    ImageView happyButton;
    @Bind(R.id.soso)
    ImageView sosoButton;
    @Bind(R.id.angry)
    ImageView angryButton;


    public LikeItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

}