# How to change an image in a ListView, when the image is clicked?

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

**EDIT: I've solved this issue, if interested, please take a look at my answer to see how I did it!**

I am currently working in Android Studio. I have a ListView that I populate with several items. Within each of these items is an ImageButton that has a "+" as the image. What I want to do is, whenever that image is clicked (not the entire ListView item, just the image), I want that image of "+" to become another image. Any help would be appreciated, as this has been an ongoing issue for a while!

Here is the current code that I attempt to use to achieve this:

```
final ImageButton movieSeen = (ImageButton convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieWatched);
        movieSeen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                movieSeen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_24dp);
            }
        });
```

Currently this does update the image that I click correctly, BUT it also updates images that are not yet rendered on the screen, so when I scroll the list view down, other objects are also changed to ic_check_circle_black_24dp.

What I want is pretty straightforward, I just don't know how to achieve it. I just want to click an ImageButton, that's inside an item on a ListView, and have that ImageButton change its image resource.

Here is my custom array adapter as requested!

```
private class MovieScrollAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movie> {//custom array adapter
    private Context context;
    private List<Movie> movies;

    public MovieScrollAdapter(Context context, List<Movie> movies){
        super(context, -1, movies);
        this.context = context;
        this.movies = movies;

        if(this.movies.isEmpty()){//if no results were returned after all processing, display a toast letting the user know
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.no_matches, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                    getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.movie_layout, parent, false);
        }

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        title.setText(movies.get(position).getTitle());

        TextView plot = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.plot);
        plot.setText(movies.get(position).getPlot());

        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        genre.setText(movies.get(position).getGenre());


        TextView metaScore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.metascore);

        if(movies.get(position).getMetaScore() == -1){//if the metaScore is set to -1, that means movie has not been rated, which by inference means it is not yet released
            metaScore.setText(R.string.movie_not_released);
            metaScore.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 9.5f);//smaller text so it fits without breaking anything
            metaScore.setTextColor(getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
        } else {
            metaScore.setText("    " + Integer.valueOf(movies.get(position).getMetaScore()).toString() + " ");//using white space for minor formatting, instead of altering margins each time this is rendered
            metaScore.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 25);

            //setting up a "highlighted" background to achieve metacritic square effect
            Spannable spanText = Spannable.Factory.getInstance().newSpannable(metaScore.getText());
            spanText.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(getColor(R.color.metaScore)), 3, 7, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            metaScore.setText(spanText);
            metaScore.setTextColor(getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_dark));

        }

        ImageView image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        new ImageDownloadTask((ImageView)image).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, movies.get(position).getPosterURL());//because there are several images to load here, we let these threads run parallel

        title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {//setting up a simple onClickListener that will open a link leading to more info about the movie in question!
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse(movies.get(position).getMovieURL());
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        final ImageButton movieSeen = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieWatched);
        movieSeen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                movieSeen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_24dp);
            }
        });




        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Comment: show your adapter and ill give you a solution

Comment: See my answer here. You need to put a else condition inside your adapter. Maintain some other list to keep track which item is clicked. http://stackoverflow.com/a/36327143/3145960

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to thank everyone for their support. Unfortunately, with the way my code is written (rather messily and without much regard for what my professors taught me), I was unable to get most of these solutions to work. I did however, find a solution that falls in line with my own framework that I've had going into this. Unfortunately I could not redo my entire adapter method, or implement various interfaces that would cause me to have to rewrite a huge chunk of code for something seemingly trivial.

**So, if anyone finds themselves in this situation in the future, here is my solution:**

In the Movie class, I add a boolean value that represents my values, along with some getters and setters:

```
private boolean watchedStatus;
public boolean hasSeen() {return watchedStatus;}

public void toggleWatchedStatus(){
    watchedStatus = !watchedStatus;
}
```

In the getView method, I simply get a reference to the ImageButton, and then based on the boolean value returned by "hasSeen," I set the ImageResource to one of two states:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

ImageButton movieSeen = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieSeen);
        if(movies.get(position).hasSeen()){
            movieSeen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_24dp);
        } else {
            movieSeen.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_circle_black_24dp);
        }

}
```

Next, I override the OnClickListener, and make it so that whenever the button is clicked, the boolean value in the Movie.java class is toggled. The key here was using the ArrayAdapter's method "notifyDataSetChanged()" This completes the process, and lets the ListView know that it should update itself:

```
final ImageButton movieSeenForClick = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieSeen);
movieSeen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    //movieSeenForClick.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_circle_black_24dp);
        movies.get(position).toggleWatchedStatus();
        System.out.println(movies.get(position).hasSeen() + " ------- position: " + position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Thanks again for the time taken to provide information, a lot of it really did steer me int he right direction, I just had to use the information correctly with the way my code was structured.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on a ListView, the views are being reused to save memory and avoid creating a lot of views, so when you change a view it keeps the state while it's being reused to show another item.

For example, you have 100 elements, you touch the first element ImageButton and that button is changed. Maybe on the screen there are 5 elements of the list showing, and you changed the first one. But if you scroll to the element number 15 the system is not creating 15 views, is taking the first one you clicked before and is changing the content. 
So, you are expecting to have a view with a "+" ImageButton icon but you see another icon, that's because you must keep the view state inside a model object and set the state every time 'getView' is called.

Post your list adapter to see how is implemented.

UPDATE:
Now I see your adapter implementation I suggest you to add an int field inside Movie class to save the resource id you want to show on the ImageButton. Then inside the `onClickListener` you must set to this field the resource you want to show on the view when its clicked, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. After that you must do inside getView():

```
movieSeen.setImageResource(movies.get(position).getButtonImageResource());
```

Comment: You are right but using a ListView frank wont be able to set the click listener just on the image (he said "whenever that image is clicked (not the entire ListView item, just the image)" )

Comment: If the view is an ImageButton, setting the click listener on the ImageButton provides the expected behavior, so his implementation of click listener is ok.

Answer (score 1):

Use [RecyclerView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html) and set the OnItemClickListener on your ImageButton within your view holder.

This already answered [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449540/android-handling-clicks-on-image-view-inside-recyclers-view-item-using-touch-f) should help.

The adapted code below is coming from this nice [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html). Using ReciclerView with an adapter like this will solve your concern.

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<String> mDataset;

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView imageView;
    public TextView txtHeader;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        txtHeader = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.xxx);
        imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.yyy);
    }
}

public MyAdapter(ArrayList<String> myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public MyAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    final String name = mDataset.get(position);
    holder.txtHeader.setText(mDataset.get(position));


    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Do here what you need to change the image content
        }
    });

    holder.itemView.setBackground(....); // Initialize your image content here...

}

//...
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion to achieve what you want :

1. Create An Interface in your adapter :

> ```
> public interface YourInterface{
>         void selectedImage(int position,ImageView iamgeView);   
>     }
> ```

2. Create variable interface in your adapter that you just created :

> ```
> private YourInterface yourInterface;
> ```

and make your adapter constructor like this :

> ```
> public YourAdapterConstructor(YourInterface yourInterface){
>
>         this.yourInterface = yourInterface;
>     }
> ```

in your ImageView onClickListener :

> ```
> final ImageButton movieSeen = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieWatched);
>         movieSeen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>             @Override
>             public void onClick(View v) {
>                 yourInterface.selectedImage(position, imageView);
>             }
>         });
> ```

and then finally in your class activity, Implements YourInterface and change you ImageView there :

> ```
> @Override
>
>     public void selectedImage(final int position,final ImageView imageView) {
> //change your image view here
> }
> ```

Comment: I always use this workaround to make my list view and my activity communicate each other, and for me it is also easier when you want to change or modify your project in the future